# silent keyword not working in vim for external commands

Tags: vim

I was working on a vimscript that executes `lgrep` silently. However, the `silent` keyword *would not work* for any external command that is run. `lmake`, `lgrep`, etc all still dump their output despite the `silent` keyword used before the command.

How do I suppress the output??

Example:

```
:silent lgrep -R a *
```

The above command would dump out all results, forcing the user to press enter. I can't reproduce his problem on my machine, in bash/zsh/tmux/screen/terminal/iterm/vim 7.3/vim 7.4/anything. Any tips would be appreciated.

*UPDATE*:

I still have no idea what the problem is, but I found a workaround that goes something like this:

```
silent !grep -Rn a * >/tmp/lgrep_output.txt
lf /tmp/lgrep_output.txt
```

Run the raw external grep command (not lgrep) silently (this successfully suppresses the output, but `:lgrep` doesn't), redirecting the output to a file. Then load the file into the location list (`lf /tmp/lgrep_output.txt`)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either. Perhaps a PEBKAC problem? Do you know what OS/vim/term the user has?

Comment: what happens if he starts vim with the command `vim -u NONE`?  It's possible a plugin he has is somehow messing something up

Comment: we tried specifically running vim under a new user that had no plugins, no `.vimrc`, and no special environment variables. We've tried stock vim 7.3 that comes on a mac, plus vim 7.4 that you get if you install with homebrew. Tried inside tmux/screen/plain shell with sh/bash/zsh in iterm and terminal. It's really odd :^/ All combinations "worked on my machine" but never worked on his